# Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem() not working in sitecore events

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7

I am using `Sitecore 7.0`. `Visual Studio 2013`. I want to create an item's child in Sitecore using event Handler. So whenever an item is created, its child automatically added. For this I wrote an eventHandler on "`item:added`" event.

But I am getting `NullReferenceException` exception "`Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`."

I figure out that `Database.GetItem()` method is not working in Sitecore Events.

```
Item entryFolderItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Site Config/Configuration/Entry Folders Structure");
```

The above item exist in sitecore and I have also tried with `ID`. But still I get the same error.

I also tried the same code on event `item:saved` but still I get the same error.

Any suggestion for this problem!!

By the way [here](https://csuwannarat.wordpress.com/2011/08/10/trigger-field-update-with-custom-event-handler-itemsaved/) you can find a nice article on events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assume you can get a context. Besides, going for context database would be wrong, so would be going for a hardcoded "master" database.

When you extract the Item from EventArgs, use the .Database definition from there to perform your operations.

```
Item eventItem = eventArgs.Parameters[0] as Item;
Database db = eventItem.Database;
```

More information here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-intercepting-item-updates-with-sitecore

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to access the `Sitecore.Context.Database` and it was not working. Then I tried with `MasterDB`

```
     Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
   Item entryFolderItem = masterDb.Items["/sitecore/content/Site Config/Configuration/Entry Folders Structure"]
```

And it worked out successfully.